# Cant get type from entry.Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to build a generic method for fuzzy disconnected entity graphs. So I'm trying to verify if the entity exists, for properly state modification

```
 private static void ApplyChanges<TEntity>(TEntity root)
        where TEntity : class, IObjectWithState
    {
        using (var context = new MainContext())
        {
            context.Set<TEntity>().Add(root);

            CheckForEntitiesWithoutStateInterface(context);

            var entries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IObjectWithState>();

            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                //Here i try to get the type in my entries that are being tracked
                var type = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entry.Entity.GetType());

                //context.Set<type> not regonizing the type correct.
                var entity = context.Set<type>();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the non-generic method [DbContext.Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)?

Comment: this is the right answer... - > context.set(entry.Entity.GetType());

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke a generic method with a variable of type `Type`. Instead, you'll need to invoke the method via reflection. For example:

```
var setMethod = context.GetType().GetMethod("Set").GetGenericMethodDefinition();
var setMethodForType = setMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
var entity = setMethodForType.Invoke(context, new object[0]);
```

Unfortunately, at this point entity will be of type object, so further operations on it will also require reflection. One way to get around this is to create your own generic method and just reflectively invoke that, so you can get back into the "type-safe" world:

```
var doStuffMethod = [current type].GetMethod("DoStuff", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .GetGenericMethodDefinition()
    .MakeGenericMethod(type);
doStuffMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { context });

private static void DoStuff<TEntity>(MainContext context) {
    // here you can do
    context.Set<TEntity>();
}
```